# Assign validation groups Symfony 2.5

Tags: validation, symfony

I have Entity with some fields, for example name and name has validation group:

```
<?php

namespace RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"qqq"})
     */
    protected $name;
```

My FormType:

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
      $this->buildUserForm($builder, $options);
      $builder->add('name', null, array(
          'label'         => 'Name',
          'attr'          => array(
              'class'         =>'form-control', 
              'placeholder'   =>'Name'
      )));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'            => $this->class,
            'intention'             => 'profile',
            'validation_groups'     => array('qqq')
        ));
    }
```

Problem is there that my validation group 'qqq' doesn't work, I can submit form with empty name input. In Symfony documentation is said that validation groups can pass trough setDefaultOptions method, like I did, but it just doesn't work. What I have missed?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
After some testing I can say that there only works 'default' validation group, not my definied 'qqq'.